# PHANTOMJS PHP : Empty response object

Tags: php, laravel-5, phantomjs, response

When I try to save the file locally, the response object is returned null .The page I'm trying to capture takes a lot of loading time for which I need a callback to notify me when all page resources are completely loaded. Is my approach correct ?

When not trying to save the file locally the response object returned is not null.

Here's my code:

```
$client = Client::getInstance();
$client->getEngine()->setPath('path/to/phantomjs');
    $client->isLazy();

    $request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createPdfRequest('http://google.com');
    $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

    $file = 'path/binfile.pdf';

    $request->setOutputFile($file);

    $client->send($request, $response);
```

How do I achieve and know when all the page resources are completely loaded ?

Answer (score 2):

> The solution for me was to install phantomjs from my package manager
>   (sudo apt-get install phantomjs) and refer the engine to it, rather
>   than to the phantomjs binary downloaded by composer.
>
> $this->client->getEngine()->setPath('/usr/bin/phantomjs');

For more info refer this thread : https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/issues/86

or even this thread: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/issues/57

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. I've used [jonnyw/php-phantomjs](https://packagist.org/packages/jonnyw/php-phantomjs) in laravel.

User setTimeout function. it works for me. try this.

```
$request->setOutputFile($file);
$request->setTimeout(10000);
```

Hope it helps.